# Ставится здесь запятая и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Доложил командир ППС, Майор Пупкин.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны в зависимости от ситуации.

(1) *Доложил командир ППС **майор Пупкин*** (из рапорта).

Два **неоднородных** приложения относятся к имени собственному (должность и звание), запятая между ними не ставится.

(2) *Об этом доложил командир ППС, **майор Пупкин**.* Имя собственное имеет **уточняющее** значение (а именно).